# vb.net DAL Specify columns returned

Tags: vb.net, data-access-layer, 3-tier

I have a Data Access Layer class that has a method (GetPeople) that will retrieve records from a SQL Server table (people). This table has more than 20 fields, including `varbinary` type.

Right now, SQL query is something like

```
SELECT * FROM people
```

From my BLL class, I will call `DAL.GetPeople()`, which will return all columns.

What would be the best way to specify which columns to return, so I could improve performance? For example, sometimes I would like to return all fields, other times, just one or two.

**UPDATE**
To explain it better:
In DAL I have a method GetPeople() which calls a SQL Server function GetPeople.
In BLL I have a method GetPeople() which calls DAL.GetPeople(), after doing some business logic.
In my presentation layer, I call BLL.GetPeople().

This is working, but on SQL function, I have "SELECT * FROM people". Sometimes I would like to retrieve only one column (eg. name) from table, but in this case all columns are returned, which I think is affects performance.

So, I would like to have a kind of dynamic SELECT query on this SQL Server function, whose columns returned would depend on how I call the function...

Comment: I think it depends on how you have written your DAL. ADO, EF, Simple.Data? As it stands this might be too open ended a question?

Comment: The important thing is what type is your GetPeople method returning - Classes, datasets, other? Also, don't use Select * from ANYTHING. Specify the columns explicitly.

Comment: a dataset... is what this method would return. Of course, I don't want to use "*", that's why I want to specify columns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are after something like this where you can pass in a comma-seperated list of column names

```
Private Function GenerateQuery(ByVal columnNames As String) As String

    '   columnNames in the following format 'column1,column2,column3'
    Dim lstColumnNames As String() = Split(columnNames, ",")
    Dim strSQL As New StringBuilder
    strSQL.Append("SELECT ")
    For intColNumber As Integer = 0 To lstColumnNames.GetUpperBound(0)
        strSQL.Append("[")
        strSQL.Append(lstColumnNames(intColNumber))
        strSQL.Append("]")
        If intColNumber < lstColumnNames.GetUpperBound(0) Then
            strSQL.Append(", ")
        End If
    Next
    strSQL.Append(" FROM People ")
    Return strSQL.ToString

End Function
```

You can use it like this: SqlCommand.CommandText = GenerateQuery("column1,column2,column3")

The column names are wrapped in [] symbols so you don't have to worry about reserved words causing the database to error.

Comment: This is what I've thought first place, but SQL query is on database (function), so the only way I can think about is passing fields string to this function and build query dynamically on that function, and then execute command using sp_executesql...

Comment: Yes, as far as I'm aware in that case there is little point having the function in the database because it will be dynamically generated and therefore not optimal in the way a static function would be. Personally I'd generate the string in the application, but that's just me :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL-query to something like

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM people;
```

EDIT:

What you are going to need to do is create function that will put your SQL string together for you. When i did this before, I had all of the available fields in a checked-list control, and if i wanted them pulled, I checked them. The checked items were then put through the function to assemble the string. It should be pretty simple since there are not any joins going on.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain right. Sometimes I want to "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM people", other times "SELECT column1 FROM people;" and other times "SELECT * FROM people;". I was just looking for a way to control which fields I would return.